# How to make setOnKeyPressed work with MouseEvent.mouse_entered?

Tags: java, events, javafx, mouseevent

I'm having difficulties making the method setOnKeyPressed work with MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED. My goal was to have the setOnKeyPressed event run ONLY when mouse is over the node (Shapes more precisely) in a Stage, but my setOnKeyPressed method is called even if mouse isn't on the shape.
Here's how i create the Shapes:

```
Circle circle= new Figura().createCircle(40, 50, 50, Color.BLACK);
root.getChildren().add(circle);
circle.setCenterX(stage.getWidth()/2);
circle.setCenterY(stage.getHeight()/2);
addMouseScrolling(circle);          
addKeyPressed(circle); // this handle the 'KeyPressed' and 'Mouse_Entered' events
circle.requestFocus();
```

And here's how I handled the mouseEvent + setOnKeyPressed stuff:

```
public void addKeyPressed(Node node) {
   node.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, e -> {
       node.setOnKeyPressed(t -> {

           if (t.getCode()==KeyCode.R) System.out.println("Key "R" pressed!");
       });
    });
```

}

As I said I would like to have the setOnKeyPressed method called ONLY when mouse is over the node, now I have it called always, not only if mouse is over the node: I create the circle (just creating it doesn't make the setonkeypressed work) then I click it and from now on when I press "r" ANYWHERE I have printed on console "Key "R" pressed". I hope I was clear explaining my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a `KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED` handler, and add `if (node.isHover) { ... }` to your handler:

```
public void addKeyPressed(Node node) {
    node.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
        if (node.isHover()) {
            if (e.getCode()==KeyCode.R) System.out.println("Key "R" pressed!");
        }
    });
}
```

You can also do this by adding and removing the key event handler as follows:

```
public void addKeyPressed(Node node) {
    EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyHandler = e -> {
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.R) {
            System.out.println("Key \"R\" pressed!");
        }
    } ;
    node.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, e -> {
        node.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyHandler);
    });
    node.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, e -> {
        node.removeEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyHandler);
    });
}
```

This version allows you to automatically request focus on the node when the mouse enters it. Just modify the mouse entered handler:

```
    node.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, e -> {
        node.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyHandler);
        node.requestFocus();
    });
```

Comment: I replaced 'KeyEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED' with 'KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED' otherwise it gave me error. Now it's working perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: Oops: yes, sorry - I just copied the original and forgot to change that. @Sedrick thanks for the edit.

Comment: ehm, there's another problem now: this is working only for the last shape I created. I create a rect and the KeyEvent works properly, then if I create another shape the KeyEvent works for this last one but not for the first i created.

Comment: @AndreaCristiani Probably because only one node can have keyboard focus?

Comment: ye, I'm checking how to fix this. Thanks again for support.

Comment: @AndreaCristiani Added another approach which should make it easier to handle keyboard focus.